# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '"untitled" | null | undefined'

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I can't understand something about TypeScript's type inference.  I thought this should be valid and wouldn't require me to specify the type of `T`:

```
export const deflt = <T>(val: (T | undefined | null), defaultVal: T): T => {
  if (val === undefined || val === null) {
    return defaultVal;
  }
  return val;
}

function maybeLabelName(name: string | undefined) {
  return deflt(name, 'untitled');
}
```

The call to deflt fails with the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '"untitled" | null | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"untitled" | null | undefined'. [2345]
```

I can fix it by changing the `deflt` call to one of the following:

```
// Option 1:
return deflt<string>(name, 'untitled');

// Option 2:
const s: string = 'untitled';
return deflt(name, s);
```

Shouldn't TypeScript infer the `string` type automatically?

Comment: What version of TypeScript do you use?

Comment: @finico You ca reproduce in the latest TS, you just need `strictNullCkecks` turned on

Comment: I'm using TypeScript 3.1.6.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bit of a quirk in the way typescript infers `T` in this case. Because you specify the constant `'untitled'`, the compiler will infer `T` as the string literal type `'untitled'`, since that is the simplest site to infer  `T` from. It will then check the other parameter against the string literal type and find that `string` is not assignable to `'untitled'`. A work around would be to decrease the priority of the second parameter when inferring `T` by adding an extra intersection with `{}`:

```
export const deflt = <T>(val: (T | undefined | null), defaultVal: T & {} ): T => {
    if (val === undefined || val === null) {
        return defaultVal;
    }
    return val;
}

function maybeLabelName(name: string | undefined) {
    return deflt(name, 'untitled'); // T is string now
}
```

Another solution (if ou can't change the original function) would be to explicitly assert `untitled` to `string`, which is basically what you already tried.

```
function maybeLabelName(name: string | undefined) {
    return deflt(name, 'untitled' as string); // T is string now
}
```

Comment: This feels almost like a bug.

Comment: @Nurpax you could post it to GitHub .. but this also infers the string literal type `export const deflt = <T>(val: T): T => { return val; }
deflt('untitled'); // T is '"untitled"'`

Comment: Admittedly this really strikes me as counterintuitive and rather odd behavior. Do you think this is worth an issue against Typescript or would it just be "works as designed"? Edit: too slow :)

Answer (score 0):

When you're using generics, there can be two different ways of "generifying" a parameter.

Using your case as an example:

`const deflt = <T>(val: (T | undefined | null), defaultVal: T): T`

If you use: `deflt<string>(a, b)`, then you're forcing `a` to be `string | undefined | null` and `b` to be `string`.

If you use: `deflt(a: string, b: "untitled")`, the transpiler understand `"untitled"` as a constant, not as a string. Therefore, `b` will be of type `"untitled"`, thus making `T` be of type `"untitled"`. As you're using `a` of type `string`, the compiler can't cast `string` to `"untitled"`.

The solution is already provided by [@Titian Cernicova-Dragomir answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53472210/8038345)

Answer (score 0):

You've declared deflt as a generic function, but have used it as a regular function

```
const deflt = <T>(val: (T | undefined | null), defaultVal: T): T => {
    if (val === undefined || val === null) {
      return defaultVal;
    }
    return val;
}

function maybeLabelName(name?: string) {
    return deflt<typeof name>(name, 'untitled');
}
```

Comment: I don't think TypeScript requires me to specify the type arguments to generic functions.  Type inference should handle that.  See e.g., https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html "Notice that we didn’t have to explicitly pass the type in the angle brackets (<>); the compiler just looked at the value "myString", and set T to its type."

Comment: Yes, it's a bug [https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9366](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9366)

Comment: Excellent, found a couple of similar bugs while filing a bug against TypeScript and decided not to file a new bug.  Thanks for the link!